# Convert Uri to Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, android-bitmap, android-image

I want to convert a Uri from the .takePicture method to a Bitmap for later use, I searched for different methods but each gaved me an error saying that the bitmap is null and sometimes "int android.graphics.bitmap.getwidth()' on a null object reference".

```
var imageUri:Uri?=null
    private fun takePhoto() {

        val photofile = File(externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull(), "picture - ${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")
        val output = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photofile).build()
        var image_View = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)

        imageCapture?.takePicture(output, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Pic saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                imageUri = outputFileResults.savedUri
                //image_View.setImageURI(imageUri)
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error saving pic!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `getSavedUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OutputFileResults#getSavedUri()):

> This field is only returned if the `ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions` is backed by `MediaStore` constructed with `#Builder(ContentResolver, Uri, ContentValues)`

That is not the constructor that you are using for `OutputFileOptions`. So, check to see if `getSavedUri()` is returning `null`. If it is, you will need to use `photofile`, including taking steps to save that in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

If `getSavedUri()` is returning a non-`null` value, you might want to edit your question and supply the complete stack trace associated with your crash (rather than using a pastebin).

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

Comment: My app just crashes when I try this and also getBitmap is crossed out.

Comment: Can you let me know the stacktrace please?